# How to stop loading page after click on link?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, reload, mailto

I have a link:

```
<a href="mailto:abc@abc.com">abc@abc.com</a>
```

it works perfectly. But even when Outlook is open, the page is still loading.

How can I stop this loading process and Redirect to a certain page. I know that I should use something like responde.redirect, but I dont know where to insert it, in the Code behind.

Comment: That  isn't an http url - there is no page and there is no request... there is no request for your site  to respond to. Basically, this is a browser / OS configuration issue. What "page" is still loading?

Comment: on a masterpage

Comment: that... doesn't answer the question